# Replacing the text of a given Range by a merge field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm creating a VBA macro which looks for words between `<>` markers in a Word document, and turns them into merge fields.

This is the first script I came up with

```
Sub lookForFields()
    '
    ' lookForFields Macro
    '
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\<(.*?)\>"
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim region As Word.Range
    Dim allmatches As MatchCollection
    Dim currentWord As String

    Debug.Print (vbCrLf + "------------------")
    Dim res As String
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        txt = para.Range.Text
        Set allmatches = regEx.Execute(txt)
        For Each m In allmatches
            Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=m.FirstIndex + para.Range.Start, End:=m.FirstIndex + Len(m.Value) + para.Range.Start)
            'Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=m.Value)
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Next m
    Next para
End Sub
```

The following instruction correctly highlights the words I'd like to have converted:

```
rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
```

However, if I uncomment

```
Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=m.Value)
```

Merge fields won't be created if there are more than one in a paragraph. 
The created merge fields also somehow don't seem "valid" since right clicking them to edit their properties replaces them with an "unknow switch" error.
How should I go about this one?

Comment: Why would you not use Word's built-in Find capacity, using wildcards, which would let you insert the MergeField directly into the target Range. Relying on the Start and End values is extremely unreliable, as you've discovered...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Alt-F9 to see what is actually happening in your document, you will probably see that the second and subsequent fields in each paragraph are being inserted inside the first field that the code inserted.

This is because field insertion changes the number of characters in the document's range. Nothing will adjust the range start and end values recorded in your MatchCollection's Match objects automatically.

The usual way to deal with this kind of thing is to iterate backwards through the document, i.e. backwards through the paragraphs, then backwards through the Match items.

Another thing that appeared relevant here was that the m variable was undeclared. I think it probably needs to be declared as a Regex Match object.

So you need code more like this:

```
Sub lookForFields()
    '
    ' lookForFields Macro
    '
    Dim m As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    Dim theMatch As Long
    Dim thePara As Long
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\<(.*?)\>"
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim region As Word.Range
    Dim allmatches As MatchCollection
    Dim currentWord As String

    Debug.Print (vbCrLf + "------------------")
    Dim res As String
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    For thePara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
      Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(thePara)
        txt = para.Range.Text
        Set allmatches = regEx.Execute(txt)
        For theMatch = allmatches.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
          Set m = allmatches(theMatch)
            Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=m.FirstIndex + para.Range.Start, End:=m.FirstIndex + Len(m.Value) + para.Range.Start)
            Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=m.Value)
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Next
    Next
    Set m = Nothing
    Set para = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot @bibadia.